# Devolver el array capitalizado

Tags: javascript

Por qué no devuelve la primera letra en mayúscula?

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 

  var strArray = str.split(' '),maxA = strArray.length,j=0;
  for(;j<maxA;j++){
      strArray[j][0] = strArray[j][0].toUpperCase();
  }
  return strArray.join(' ');       
}
console.log(LetterCapitalize('eduardo sebastian'));
```

En mi código intento enviar como parámetro una cadena y devolver la primera letra de las palabras en mayúscula, pero no funciona, por qué?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por buenas practicas nunca escribas en un parametro de `entrada` en tu caso `str`,

> por cierto cuando accedes a una variable `char` de una cadena es modo `lectura`

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
  var strArray = str.split(' '),maxA = strArray.length,j=0;
  let arrayReturn = [];
  for(;j<maxA;j++){
  
    arrayReturn[j] = strArray[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArray[j].slice(1);
  }
  return arrayReturn.join(' ');       
}
let miCadena = "mi cadena";
miCadena[0] = "J";
console.log(miCadena);
console.log(LetterCapitalize('eduardo sebastian'));
```

Comment: Como escribir en un parametro de entrada? no entendí eso